# What do the $p$-adic roots of unity look like?

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I know that $\mathbb{Z}_p$ has all the $p-1^{st}$ roots of unity (and only those). Is it true that mod $p$ they are all different? Meaning, is the natural map $\mathbb{Z}_p \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_p$, restricted to just the roots of unity, bijective?

Comment: Yes, by Hensel's Lemma (and the generalisation also holds for the algebraic extensions of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and $\mathbb{F}_p$). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma

Comment: The "and only those" part is wrong when $p=2$.

Answer (score 16):

Indeed, the $(p-1)^{st}$ roots of unity are the so-called [Teichmüller lifts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teichm%C3%BCller_representative) of the non-zero elements of $\mathbb{F}_p$. This construction is very important, because it generalises to Witt vectors, as the article explains, and those are widely used in number theory.

Answer (score 8):

This follows from the fact that $x^{p-1} - 1$ is relatively prime to its formal derivative over $\mathbb{F}_p$, which is $-x^{p-2}$.